# React conditional onClick with ampersand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, onclick

I want to edit a card if `allowed=true`. I came up with this solution:

```
const editCard = (onEdit, id, allowed) => {
    if (allowed) {
        onEdit(id);
    }
};

<Card onClick={() => editCard(onEdit, id, allowed)}>Card</Card>
```

I thought of making a simpler onClick like so:

```
<Card onClick={() => allowed && onEdit(id)}>Card</Card>
```

Can I make on onClick like so with the ampersand? If `allowed=true` then edit, otherwise onClick should not do anything.

It seems to work but I don't know if it will `always` work. Can this cause bugs and is there a better way to implement this click event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will work as expected :)

`true && something()` calls `something` function

`false && something()` returns just `false` while not calling `something`

Comment: thanks so basically if allowed=false onClick will call a function that returns false

Comment: @user2456977 yes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work. But you may also use like:

```
<Card allowed onClick={() => onEdit(id)}>Card</Card>
```

Then check the allowed props.

Just using `allowed` is equivalent to `allowed={true}`. If the allowed option is false you want to send, you don't need to pass the props.

But in your case, it's dynamic. So, you can use like:

```
<Card allowed={allowed} onClick={() => onEdit(id)}>Card</Card>
```

So, depending on the case it will be either `allowed={true}` or `allowed={false}`.

---

And oh, you want to use it in editCard, so you may just use like:

```
 <Card onClick={() => onEdit(id, allowed)}>Card</Card>
```

A good use case with conditional statement would be to use like: (only show card if allowed is true)

```
 {
   allowed &&
   <Card onClick={() => onEdit(id)}>Card</Card>
 }
```

This way, you're ensuring clear instruction with your code. So, you found sorts of ways. Happy coding!